# Error configuring flask-babel method jinja2 not found

Tags: python, flask, translation, flask-babel

This is my babel.cfg file:

```
[python: **.py]
[jinja2: **/templates/**.html]
```

When I execute this command:

`pybabel extract -F babel.cfg -k _l -o messages.pot .`

Then return this error:

```
ValueError: Unknown extraction method 'jinja2'
```

[image: Error detail]

¿How is it possible? That example of config is literally gotten from docs

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly:

sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools

Updating the setuptools on my mac and now it works...